# Testing spring boot application with embedded mongo

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, database

My application has 
Spring boot
Spring data
Mongo db.

I am trying to do unit test case for dao layer using embedded mongo.while searching in internet, I came across two annotations 
*@springboottest
*@testsbmongo..

I am confused with this annotations usage.my question is
1.what is the difference between these annotations
2. i am getting connection refused error when I am using 
@testdbmongo
3.how to use this embedded mongo for test when my original mongo server is running

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **Fongo**. Its an in-memory mongoDB similar to h2 database , which we use for RDBMS dao layer test.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.fakemongo</groupId>
    <artifactId>fongo</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
```